# Replacing the clearIndicator X with custom text in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need to remove the clearIndicator's default X in the select component on MultiSelect and replace it with custom text. Is there a way to do this without losing the ability to remove the selected options (as happens with isClearable={false})?

Code:

```
export const MultiSelect = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const options = [
    { value: '1', label: 'Label1' },
    { value: '2', label: 'Label2' },
    { value: '3', label: 'Label3' },
  ];

const customStyles = {
    control: (prevStyle, { isFocused }) => ({
      ...prevStyle,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(248, 251, 251, 1)',
      boxShadow: 'none',
      borderColor: isFocused ? 'black' : 'grey',
      ':hover': {
        borderColor: isFocused ? 'black' : 'grey',
      },
    }),
    clearIndicator: (prevStyle) => ({
      ...prevStyle,
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
      ':hover': {
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
      },
    }),
  };

return (
    <ReactSelect
      ref={reactSelectRef}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      instanceId={`multiselect-${id}`}
      styles={customStyles}
      isOptionSelected={isMulti && isOptionSelected}
      options={getOptions()}
      value={getValue()}
      onChange={isMulti ? onChangeHandler : onChange}
      hideSelectedOptions={false}
      closeMenuOnSelect={!isMulti}
      formatGroupLabel={formatGroupLabel}
      isMulti={isMulti}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using React-Select https://react-select.com/home ? The componet for react select is <Select />

Comment: Yes, I had just grabbed the wrong return statement when copying. It's edited now.

Comment: Um still not sure what library you're using. Or did you mean to change that to <Select />?

Comment: BTW what you're asking can be done with the react-select library I just want to make sure you're using it before answering

Comment: Yup, it's absolutely react-select. It's just heavily customised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Select has an option of passing in your own custom Components [Docs](https://react-select.com/components)

Would look something like this

```
 <Select
    //You can pass in any component as the ClearIndidcator and do whatever customizations you want
    components={{ ClearIndicator: () => <div>Clear</div> }}
    {...props}
 />
```

Comment: Thank you! I even tried something very similar earlier. Not sure how I could have messed that one up tbh... Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

A better solution that I found

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const CustomClearText = () => <>Clear</>;

const ClearIndicator = (props) => {
  const { children = <CustomClearText />, getStyles, innerProps } = props;
  return (
    <div {...innerProps} style={getStyles('clearIndicator', props)}>
      <div style={{ padding: '0px 5px' }}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const selectionStyles = {
  clearIndicator: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    color: state.isFocused ? '#585858' : '#ccc',
    fontWeight: 500,
  }),
  // Add more custom styles here if needed
};

const eventOptions = [
  // Define your options here
];

const SelectComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Select
      defaultValue={[]}
      name="events"
      options={eventOptions}
      styles={selectionStyles}
      placeholder="Select Category"
      components={{ ClearIndicator }}
      classNamePrefix="select"
    />
  );
};

export default SelectComponent;
```